# Every banach manifold is locally arcwise conneted

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

I found this inside a proof of another fact. I've been trying to find any result to prove it, but I couldn't find any. Does someone know this result or how to prove it? I'm working with a manifold inside $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, if it can help by any way.

Comment: A Banach manifold is locally arcwise connected since a Banach space is : in a Banach space open balls are arcwise connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Banach space has the property that all its open balls are locally convex, hence arcwise-connected. So all Banach manifolds are locally arcwise-connected too.

Comment: I think my confusion was caused by the fact that I was trying to use just the definition (chart, atlas, e.g.). Do u know where I could find some results to help me prove that $M=f^{-1}({1})$ where $f\in C^{1}$ is a Banach Manifold? Inside Sobolev Spaces